# how to create custom enumerator in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I'm looking for a way to create custom enumerator for collection on the example of `sum` enumerator - using `reduce()` several times that only sums value is not a good solution.

The `Enumerable` API says that an enumerator has to implement `nextObject` method and have `length` property. But not all the built-in enumerators seem to have them.

I tried with reopening the `Ember.Enumerable` class but it failed.

An example how to create a `sum` enumerator based on `reduce` (or a resource how to do it) will be a great help.

## edit

```
# custom enumarator I want to have
sum = @get('items').sum(0)

# current solution
sum = @get('items').reduce ((prev, curr) -> prev + curr,) 0
```

Ember has `Em.computed.sum` but I couldn't find it as a normal enumerable.

Comment: This question is confusing, Can you provide some ember-ish pseudo-code of what you want to do?

Comment: Updated question as requested.

Comment: A js bin example could help the others to jump in and find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing enumerating functions and enumerable objects.

An object that is enumerable will have to implement `nextObject` and `length`. These are things like linked lists, queues, stacks, and sets. Basically, data structures that you would want to iterate.

An enumerating function is something you can apply to an enumerable object, like `sum`, `min`, `max`.

You should not be adding this method to Ember.Enumerable because not all enumerables can be summed. A list of numbers can, but how would you sum a collection of fruits?

That said, this should answer you question:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nodojadi/1/edit

Comment: Nice! Now I've got it! :)

Comment: Unfortunately when I try to sum array like this: `[1, 2, 3].sum()` I got the error 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yedamuci/2/edit